# ExtJs third party dependencies do not work by default when using app.json

Tags: javascript, extjs

I generated my first application, using sencha `CMD` tool. Before I built it, I had set some dependencies in my `app.json` file. I dit it like so:

```
"js": [
    {
        "path": "app.js",
        "bundle": true
    },
    {
        "path": "resources/ol/ol.js",
        "bundle": false
    }
],
"css": [
    {
        "path": "${build.out.css.path}",
        "bundle": true,
        "exclude": ["fashion"]
    },
    {
        "path": "resources/ol/ol.css",
        "bundle": true
    }
]
```

As you can see, I try to load OpenLayers library to my application. I do not fix index.html and I do not know whether I should do it or not. But the fact is, when I go to my application in browser like so:

```
http://localhost/myapp
```

I see in console, that OpenLayers library is not loaded. When, however, I build my application using CMD and go to

```
http://localhost/myapp/build/production/myapp/
```

I see that OpenLayers library gets loaded. So, what is wrong with that and how can I load my dependencies by default, without making a build everytime?

Comment: Try `sencha app refresh` to update the bootstrap.json file which is used to load all required files. For the css file you have to run a `sencha app build development` to have the css be combined. Whenever the css changes rerun it again. Or execute a `sencha app watch` in the background which will rebuild the css file.